# Como hacer que solo admita respuesta de enteros?

Tags: python

Hola que tal soy nuevo en python y quería preguntarles como hacer una variable que solo admita números enteros como respuesta a lo que me refiero:

En C:

```
int numero;
printf("Ingrese un numero: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%i",&numero);
printf("El numero ingresado es: %i", numero);
```

Se sabe que si ingresas una cadena de caracteres o ya mismo un numero decimal dentro de esa variable que solo admite números enteros en C se produciría un error en la compilación, a lo que voy es, ¿como logro eso mismo en python? ya que en python por lo que vi no se declaran variables especificas.

Si alguien puede escribirme ese codigo mismo en lenguaje python estaria agradecido y si es posible el mismo ejemplo pero con float y char. Gracias.

Comment: simple, si solo deseas enteros, al método `input` pasalo dentro del método `int` para que haga esa verificación

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda shadow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python toma el tipo de un valor por defecto cuando le asignas un resultado, si ingresas 10, lo tomará como entero, si ingresas "jose" como cadena de caracteres, si ingresas 10.50, como float.

Para declarar que sea solamente entero, debes asignarle un entero:

> Variable_A_Usar=int(input("Ingrese numero entero"))

Para consultar si su tipo fue asignado correctamente, usa el metodo "type" para ver su tipo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Anthony, aquí estuve viendo que también se puede asignar las funciones - str() y float() - si es que lo quieres también específicamente como cadena de caracteres o numero decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Es buena idea que captures el valor ingresado y luego valides si se trata de un número con isdigit(), así evitas errores en caso de que el usuario haya ingresado un caracter no numérico.

```
     while True:
          variable_a_usar = input("Ingrese número entero: ")
          if variable_a_usar.isdigit() is True:
            variable_a_usar = int(variable_a_usar)
            break
        print("El número es %d" % (variable_a_usar))
```

Comment: Gracias rodrigo me apuntare este tip que es de muchisima ayuda!